# psycopg2 batch insert with bad data

Tags: python, postgresql, etl, psycopg2

I am building an ETL script using Python and `psycopg2`. Both source and target database are postgres. It works fine, but is a bit slow.

The structure of my program is like this:

```
import psycopg2

# create the database connections, see https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor
source_cursor = source_database_connection.conn.cursor()
destination_cursor = destination.conn.cursor()

insert_query = "INSERT INTO mytable (col1, ..., coln) VALUES (%s, ..., %s)  ON CONFLICT (key) DO UPDATE SET col1 = value1, ... ;"

for row in source_cursor:
    # data is a list with varying data types
    # mock example: data = [10, 'foo', 'bar', 123]
    # 123 might be a foreign key in mytable2
    data = some_business_logic(row)
    try:
        destination_cursor.execute(insert_query, data)
    except:
        # skip this row, log the error
```

My source table has around 10M entries, so this takes a while. In order to speed things up, I'd like to use a batch INSERT. `psycopg2` provides multiple options for this, namely `execute_batch()` and `execute_values()` ([link to documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers)). The loop would look something like this:

```
data = []
for row in source_cursor:
    # create a list of tuples with data, 
    # mock example: data =  [(10, 'foo', 'bar', '123'), (11, 'foo2', 'bar2', '124'), ...]
    data += [tuple(some_business_logic(row))]
    if num_row %10000 == 0: # or whatever batch size we want
        try:
            destination_cursor.execute_values(insert_query, data)
            data = []
        except:
            # skip all rows, log the error
```

This more or less works, but I have too many errors in my data to throw away the entire batch when there is a bad row. I could iterate over all the rows in the `data`-entries in the `except`-block, but that seems pretty bad from a performance point of view (worst case I execute every query twice).

Is there a way to speed up `INSERT ...` statements while handling errors gracefully at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post something we can test without extensive rewriting, e.g. with some stubbed out implementation of `source_cursor` and `some_business_logic`

Comment: Are the errors there are too many of conflicts on `key`, or other types of errors?

Comment: The batch condition `num_row %10000` is wrong (it will be true 99.99% of the time; I think you want: `num_row % 10000 == 0`

Comment: Regarding the process itself: can't you detect if a row is bad using Python and only add the row to the batch if it's valid?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the code a bit. @jjanes: cursors are just psycopg2 cursor objects with a connection to the source and target database. I linked the documentation in the code now. some_business_logic doesn't really matter here, I added some mock examples.

Comment: Types of errors are mainly foreign key constraint violations. Many of the fields in the target database are foreign keys in other tables (star schema). Errors occur if I try to input data into the table, where the key value doesn't appear in the other table.

Comment: @Ionut Ticus: thanks for the hint, fixed the typo. Checking within Python is not possible, I don't know which values will result in errors.

Comment: If the errors are mostly related to foreign keys it should be possible to build sets of existing keys and check your records before adding them to the batch.